# Sql Query not returning array results in model?

Tags: php, database, mysqli, model

In my scrolling feed model i'm returning the number of users in the database , and the last 50 users added to the database in ascending order. For some reason , the last 50 users are not returning.
My model code is the following:

```
<?php

//display total records in db


//add html
echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/feed.css" /><div id="feed"<marquee>
<B>Available Accounts: </B>';

//fetch amount of users
$usercount="SELECT user_name FROM store";
if ($res=mysqli_query($conn,$usercount))
  {
  // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($res);
  printf("%d",$rowcount);
  // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($res);
  } 

 //add html 
 echo 
  '<b>' . 
  ' . . . Last 50 Added Usernames . . .</b>';
//last 50 added to the database
$lastusers = mysqli_query
  ("SELECT user_name FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM store 
  ORDER BY user_id DESC
  LIMIT 50
) AS store ORDER BY user_id ASC");

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($lastusers);
echo $row['user_name'];

echo '</marquee></div>';


?>
```

Comment: your query is incorrect

Comment: which part of it? if i test the query in the database it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this out!**

```
<?php


//MySQLi information

$db_host     = "localhost";
$db_username = "username";
$db_password = "password";

//connect to mysqli database (Host/Username/Password)
$connection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password) or die("Error " . mysqli_error());

//select MySQLi dabatase table
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, "table") or die("Error " . mysqli_error());


//fetch amount of users
$usercount = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT user_name FROM store");
$rows      = mysqli_num_rows($usercount);
echo $rows . " Users!" . "<br>";


//last 50 added to the database
$row = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM store LIMIT 50");

while ($lastusers = mysqli_fetch_array($row)) {
    echo $lastusers['user_name'] . "<br>";
}
```

Tested and works fine, here is an example!
[image]

Good luck!

Comment: WOW all i needed was a while loop. THANKS

Comment: @Pacified   
Enjoy, please accept the answer by ticking the correct button ;)